# Adding a class to this element on hover using a function Angular 2/4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add a class to an element on hover using Angular 2/4.

I need to only add the class to 'this' element as I want to use this function on multiple elements but only want the class to be added to the element that is hovered over.

I'm thinking something like this:

HTML

```
<fieldset class="help-hover">
<div class="question-wrapper">
  <label class="question" for="quoteFormTitle">Your title</label>
  <div class="answer">
    <select formControlName="quoteFormTitle" id="quoteFormTitle" class="chosen-select">
      <option value="" disabled>Choose a title...</option>
      <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
      <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
      <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
      <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
      <option value="Doctor Male">Doctor - Male</option>
      <option value="Doctor Female">Doctor - Female</option>
    </select>
    <span class="tick-area"></span>
    <div class="error" *ngIf="quoteFormTitle.touched && quoteFormTitle.invalid">Please select a title.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<aside class="help">
  <p>Please select your title from the drop down list.</p>
</aside>
```

TS

```
helpHover() {
  ...
}
```

Have tried dozens of different techniques but cant get it to work.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<fieldset (mouseover)="addClass($event)" (mouseleave)="removeClass($event)">Hello</fieldset>
```

In the component:

```
  addClass(event): void {
    event.target.className += 'myClass';
  }

  removeClass(event): void {
    event.target.className = event.target.className.replace('myClass', '');
  }
```

Comment: Hi Talavera, thanks for your input. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks Talavera. I realised it's not working because I already have a class on my fieldset ('help-hover'). I have updated the code above. Whats the best way round this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class member to hold the element under the mouse:

```
export class MyComponent {
  isHovered: HTMLElement;
}
```

The value of `isHovered` would be set to the target element on `mouseover` and reset on `mouseleave`. The class would be applied to the element corresponding to `isHovered`.

```
<div #div1 [ngClass]="{'show-help': isHovered === div1 }" (mouseover)="isHovered = $event.target" (mouseleave)="isHovered = null"></div>

<div #div2 [ngClass]="{'show-help': isHovered === div2 }" (mouseover)="isHovered = $event.target" (mouseleave)="isHovered = null"></div>

<div #div3 [ngClass]="{'show-help': isHovered === div3 }" (mouseover)="isHovered = $event.target" (mouseleave)="isHovered = null"></div>
```

You can test the code in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3arsrk).

Comment: Hi ConnersFan, this is a good solution but I have over 30 elements that I have to implement this on and they are most likely to increase as time goes on. How can I make this more dynamic ie. - the numbers ('div1, div2, etc') automatically increase as more elements are added

Comment: Can you create your elements with an `ngFor` loop?

Comment: No, not at this stage

Comment: I made a change in `(mouseover)` to use `$event.target` to set the value of `isHovered`. For the condition in `ngClass` however, it looks like there has to be a different variable for each element; and I don't think that you can create them "dynamically".